# Fixed element above scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can somebody please help me with setting a fixed blue footer under the scroll bar? Here is an example of my code and HTML structure:

```js
$('#check').click(function () {
  $('body').addClass('hide-scrollbar-y');
  $('.products-pop-up').fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #adA122;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px
}

.hide-scrollbar-y {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.products-pop-up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #1c1d22;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  .container {
 height: 600px;
  }
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="check" class="button">click click </button>
<div class="products-pop-up">
  <div class="container">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you not just move footer into the body? https://jsfiddle.net/re8ztnpg/1/ - I may be misunderstanding your question as you don't really explain it very well - what is scrollBar? And do you want the element above or under it - your title contradicts your question

Comment: What do you want the footer look like?

Comment: @Kamczatka what are you trying to do?

Comment: You don't have to be older to be wiser :)

Comment: When you click button and element with class"products-pop-up" shows up, there is blue footer thats is over y-scroll. How to fix it?

Comment: running your question's code snippet results in an error...

Comment: Fixed the code snippet